# matrix multiplication within dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, matrix-multiplication

```
structure(list(var = c(8L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 10L
), rate = c(1, 0.99, 0.9801, 0.970299, 0.96059601, 0.9509900499, 
0.941480149401, 0.93206534790699, 0.92274469442792, 0.913517247483641
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

With above data I would like to calculate new variable with following formula https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hDmF.jpg , where `n` is a row number, `x` is named as `var` and `lambda = 0.99` (subsequent powers are stored as `rate` in my data). So I wanted to use matrix multiplication with subsetting parts of columns within `dplyr::mutate`, but it didn't work.

```
df %>% mutate(out = rate[1:row_number()] %*% var[row_number():1])
```

How can I calculate this new column defined according to the formula above?
desired output is shown below:

```
structure(list(var = c(8L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 10L
), rate = c(1, 0.99, 0.9801, 0.970299, 0.96059601, 0.9509900499, 
0.941480149401, 0.93206534790699, 0.92274469442792, 0.913517247483641
), out = c(8, 16.92, 19.7508, 20.553292, 27.3477571, 31.07428, 
36.76354, 38.3959, 43.01194, 52.58182)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output.  Is it `df %>% mutate(out = var %*% rev(rate))`

Comment: Or maybe with `cumsum`? Please show the desired result.

Comment: none of above. updated post with desired output.

Comment: @jogo, the results are similar but it's not an answer to my case.

Comment: basically, for example `5`-th row can be calculated in the following way: `df$rate[1:5] %*% df$var[5:1] `, but obviously I need a way to calculate that for whole column at once

Answer (score 1):

You get the desired result by:

```
df <- structure(list(var = c(8L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 10L
), rate = c(1, 0.99, 0.9801, 0.970299, 0.96059601, 0.9509900499, 
            0.941480149401, 0.93206534790699, 0.92274469442792, 0.913517247483641
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
df$out <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) sum(df$var[1:i]*df$rate[i:1]))
df
# > df
#    var      rate      out
# 1    8 1.0000000  8.00000
# 2    9 0.9900000 16.92000
# 3    3 0.9801000 19.75080
# 4    1 0.9702990 20.55329
# 5    7 0.9605960 27.34776
# 6    4 0.9509900 31.07428
# 7    6 0.9414801 36.76354
# 8    2 0.9320653 38.39590
# 9    5 0.9227447 43.01194
# 10  10 0.9135172 52.58182
```

Comment: Or using tidyverse `df %>% mutate(out = map_dbl(row_number(), ~ sum(var[seq(.x)] * rate[rev(seq(.x))])))`

Comment: Both works, but I'm wondering if there is a better solution in terms of speed using matrix multiplication.